# How to return XML from NodeJS Promise?

Tags: xml, node.js, function, promise

can anyone help me on how to return this xml as a result of this function?

I need the variable **xmlAssinado** to be returned whenever I call this function outside.

```
module.exports = { AssinarXML: function(xml, arquivo, data){
certificado.GerarPEM()
.then(function(pem){
  if (pem !== 500){ 
    const transforms = [
      'http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature',
      'http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315'
    ];
    const infoProvider = (pem) => {
      return {
        getKeyInfo() {
          const cert = this.getCert();
          return `<X509Data><X509Certificate>${cert}</X509Certificate></X509Data>`;
        },
        getCert() {
          const certLines = pem.certificate.split('\n');
          return certLines.filter((e, i) => i && e && e.indexOf('-----') !== 0).join('');
        }
      };
    };

    var signer = new SignedXml();
    signer.addReference(`//*[local-name(.)=\'infNFe\']`, transforms);
    signer.signingKey = new Buffer(pem.key);
    signer.canonicalizationAlgorithm = 'http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315';
    signer.keyInfoProvider = infoProvider(pem);
    signer.computeSignature(xml);
    **var xmlAssinado = signer.getSignedXml();**

    fs.writeFile(arquivo + '.xml', xmlAssinado, function(err) {
      if(err) {
        console.error("Ocorreu um erro na gravação do arquivo: %s", err);
      }
      else {
        console.log("XML Gerado e Assinado Com Sucesso!");
      }
    });
  } else {
    console.error("Ocorreu na assinatura do arquivo");
  }
})}}
```

What could I do to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Return the promise from your method so the caller can get access to that promise chain by adding `return` here:

```
 return certificado.GerarPEM()...
```

And, then return `xmlAssinado` at the end of your `.then()` handler with:

```
return xmlAssinado;
```

That will make the `xmlAssinado` value be the resolved value of your promise.  You can then use a `.then()` handler with the returned promise to get the desired resolved value something like this:

```
myModule.AssinarXML(...).then(function(xmlAssinado) {
    // you can use the value here
});
```

Doing the above will not wait for the `fs.writeFile()` to finish before resolving (that will continue at its own pace).  If you need to wait for that to finish, then you should promisify the writeFile operation and chain that into the promise chain too so you can resolve only when that is done also.